# How to remove all ul elements which are the child of li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<ul>
     <li>
           <ul id="remove">
               <li></li>
           </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

i want to remove `ul` by id `remove`, i use `empty()` but it clear the text of parent `li` too but i dont want this, how can i do it?

Comment: `$('li > ul').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Select `#remove` element, call `.remove()`.

```
$("#remove").remove()
```

Note, `id` of element in `document` should be unique. If you have multiple elements with `id` `"remove"`, adjust the `id` to `className` at the elements `<ul class="remove">`, then call

```
$(".remove").remove()
```